# After uploading a file using Net::Sftp, the file disappears sometimes

Tags: ruby, sftp, net-ssh, net-sftp

I use **net-sftp** gem for uploading file to remote server.

```
Net::SFTP.start(host, user, port: port, key_data: [decoded_key], keys: [], keys_only: true, logger: logger, verbose: :debug) do |sftp|
  sftp.upload!(local_file_path, remote_file_path)
end
```

Sometimes it works and file remains on the remote sftp server. And sometimes it is downloaded and soon disappears (after one or two seconds). I can see it by using FileZilla in parallel.

Sometimes one file can be uploaded successfully from the first attempt and sometimes from second or third etc.
If i use FileZilla manually or sftp from terminal then all works ok.
The debug log seems the same for success attempt and for not. No log entries indicate errors.

The gems versions:

- net-ssh (5.2.0)
- net-sftp (2.1.2)

I will be grateful for any thoughts on this issue.

Comment: What if you upload the file to localhost instead of the remote server? If it still disappears perhaps there is a problem with your code or libraries or client; if it does not disappear, then perhaps there's an issue with the remote SSH server.

Comment: Is it possible that there's a process on the remote system which removes the file?

Comment: @Kenster I don't know, the server is not under my control. But if there was such a process, then why doesn’t it delete the files that I upload using FileZilla? Also if the file remains after downloading (after 1-2 seconds), then it will not disappear.

Comment: @anothermh I think i need to find somewhere another sftp server and test on it.

Comment: Install an SSH server and do it on localhost.

Comment: @anothermh Thanks. I did that and on the new server all works ok. The problem was with the first server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on the server side.
Thank you all.